# Вызов метода при инициализации класса в PHP 7

Tags: php, ооп

Помню, в Java возможны такие конструкции:

```
public SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass().foo().bar();
```

Есть ли подобное в PHP 7.x и подойдет ли для этого конструкция вида:

```
public $someClass = (new SomeClass())->foo();
```

Или есть другие решения?

Зачем нужно:

Стоит задача - создавать запрос к БД как класс Query, который при инициализации получает значения типа запроса, таблицу(ы) и столбцы. Для запросов SELECT возможно задание параметров GROUP\ORDER, которые предполагается добавлять через отдельные функции. Хотелось бы, чтобы код инициализации экземпляра, отвечающего за запрос SELECT с параметрами GROUP\ORDER выглядел аналогично коду на Java, приведенному в начале вопроса.

Comment: https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/Structural/FluentInterface/README.html рекомендую не изобретать велосипед, а скачать уже существующую библиотеку через composer

Comment: Хм, даже и не знал об таком сервисе. Конечно, теперь буду там искать справочную инфу по реализации, но тут скорее работа ради работы, а не результата идет. Спасибо за ссылку, приятно видеть, что решение, до которого я дошел оказывается правильным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо в соответствующих методах вернуть ссылку на самого себя при помощи `return $this`:

```
class SomeClass {
    function __construct() {
        //...
    }
    
    function foo() {
        //some work
        return $this;
    }   

    function bar() {
        //some work
        return $this;
    }

}

$someClass = (new SomeClass())->foo()->bar();
```